# C# - Directory Services - Randomly receive error roughly once a month

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have a windows service that queries Active Directory User information and writes it to a database. Randomly (I'd say once a month), it errors out and does NOT successfully restart. I was wondering if anyone would know why this error seems to occur and at random intervals?

> ERROR - A local error has occurred.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADEntriesSet.MoveNext()
> at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.MoveNext()   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()

It seems to point to the last line as to what's erroring (when iterating through the collection):

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;

DateTime now1 = DateTime.Now;

PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ourdomain.org");

UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(AD);

PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal);
var all = search.FindAll();

int userCount = 0;

foreach (UserPrincipal result in all)
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: DCHP is used to assign IP addresses to computers.  A computer names is always the same.  The IP is changed periodically using DCHP protocol.  So a monthly error could indicate that the IP address was changed.  Check from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL. I think the lease expiration date may be when the IP address gets changed.  So IP addresses may be fixed on network and other assigned by DCHP.  The DCHP should be configured not to conflict with Fixed IP address.  Have seen lots of issues in past when two machines gets assigned same IP.Easy way of testing is to disconnect machine from network then ping.

Comment: It's not consistently occurring every month though. It can be 3-4 weeks or it can be 6-8 weeks between errors.

Comment: The IP could be changing every 3-4 weeks but only half the time a conflict occurs.  Keep track of the IP address of machine and see if error occur at same time the IP is changed.  Read following : https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52004/does-dhcp-client-or-server-re-assigns-the-ip-address?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rewriting your code to use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher). It may solve your problem, but even if it doesn't, you should be able to get more information about what might be going wrong. And your loop will run a whole lot faster. `PrincipalSearcher` is just a wrapper around `DirectorySearcher` anyway, but you lose a lot of control and performance.

Here's an example of what that could look like:

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry()) {
    PageSize = 1000, //this is required if you expect more than 1000 results
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))" //all users
};

//tell it which properties you want to return, otherwise it will return everything
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

using (var results = search.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        try {
            // some code

            // Get attributes from search results like:
            // (string) result.Properties["mail"][0]
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log exception
            // use result.Path to show you which user it choked on
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to update `search.PropertiesToLoad` to include the attributes you want to see from the search results.

Notice too that you can catch any exception and log that `Path` to the user that caused the exception. Then you can inspect that user and see what's different about it.

I wrote an article about getting better performance when programming against AD that could help you: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)